# BASH Loop through multiple arrays

Tags: bash, shell

So, I have an array of IP's, and an Array of Dates... Both Arrays are the same length
So, DATE[0] is the date that IP[0] was assigned...

I'm trying to parse through an entire month of logs and change the IP when it hits a certain date... I know this isn't right, so please help with my code:
(the Grep statements DO work, are from other code, basically just need to change SEARCHPATH depending on the date check....)

```
ARRAY_COUNTER=0

NEW_GREP_TERM=${IPS[0]}

for i in {01..31}
do
SEARCHPATH=${BASEPATH}/${DEF_YEAR}${DEF_MONTH}/SG_22[8-9]${DEF_MONTH}${i}*
zgrep --no-filename $NEW_GREP_TERM $SEARCHPATH | awk -f /usr/local/bin/cvsit.awk >> $OUTFILE 
 if [$i = ${DATES[$ARRAY_COUNTER]}]
        then
        NEW_GREP_TERM = ${IPS[$ARRAY_COUNTER]}
        zgrep --no-filename $NEW_GREP_TERM $SEARCHPATH | awk -f /usr/local/bin/cvsit.awk >> $OUTFILE 
        ARRAY_COUNTER=$ARRAY_COUNTER+1

fi
done
```

Comment: The code contains syntax errors and there is no question.

Comment: You have to put spaces around command names such as `[` (and the `[` command expects its last argument to be `]`, complaining if it is not).

Comment: For `bash`, it's better to use `[[` and `]]`, which is smarter but less portable. You'll have fewer syntax errors, and less confusing behavior that way.

Comment: For incrementing, use either `let ARRAY_COUNTER=$ARRAY_COUNTER+1` or `((ARRAY_COUNTER++))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As Jonathan pointed out, the `[` and `]` should have leading and post blank(s). You can run `which [` to know that the `[` is actually a command. The `if` keyword accepts the boolean  statement or variable, and the `[ foo ]` is to test the `foo` to be true or false.
2. When you would like a range of integers like `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 31`, you can use `$(seq 0 31)` in BASH. **EDIT**: The leading `0` is important here. Thus the `{...}` built-in notation is more preferable.
3. It's better to make the indent consistent. It's more human-readable.

Comment: Why is `seq` (an executable) preferable to a built-in notation? Is it because `{$min..$max}` doesn't work? Or something else?

Comment: Also, I usually recommend `[[` as a catch-all syntax "correction" to `[` -- at least for bash.

Comment: @jpaugh Consider you'd like to vary the step, i.e. 0, 2, 4, ... 32. I'm not a BASH expert. Is it possible to do it in {...}? Thanks.

Comment: @TimEagle You're right. The leading 0 is important in the code. I missed.

Comment: @liuml07 No, you can't adjust the step. Then again, I've never tried! :-)